# Verilog simulator don't execute command

Tags: verilog

I have written a program to describe the multiplexer in Figure 4.26. When I run the test bench some commands wasn't executed. I don't know where my code is wrong, can someone explain it to me

This is my code

```
module Prob438(
input [3:0]A,B,
input enable_bar,select,
output [3:0]Y);
assign Y=enable_bar?0:(select? B:A);    
endmodule
```

This is my test bench

```
module t_Prob438();
reg [3:0]A,B;
reg enable_bar,select;
wire [3:0]Y;
Prob438 M0(A,B,enable_bar,select,Y);
initial #200 $finish;
initial begin
enable_bar=1;
select=1;
A=4'hA;
B=4'h5;
#10 select=0;
#20 enable_bar=0;
#30 A=4'h0;
#40 A=4'hF;
#50 enable_bar=1;
#60 select=1;
#70 enable_bar=0;
#80 B=4'h0;
#90 B=4'hA;
#100 B=4'hF;
#110 enable_bar=1;
#120 select=0;
#130 select=1;
#140 enable_bar=1;
end
endmodule
```

[Error2][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNWuX.png

[Fig 4.26]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMdPM.png

[Error1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvhju.png

Simulator doesn't execute commands

```
#20 enable_bar=0;

#40 A=4'hF;
#50 enable_bar=1;

#70 enable_bar=0;
#80 B=4'h0;
#90 B=4'hA;

#110 enable_bar=1;
#120 select=0;
#130 select=1;
```

Comment: You should provide detailed description of what is wrong with your model: what data did you expect and what you got.  Do not insert pointers to the picture in the question.

Comment: i just added some information about my problem

Answer (score 1):

The total run time of the testbench is 200 units because of the $finish.  The testbench is making assignments for longer than that.  The delays accumulate.  The assignments for #10 #20 #30 #40 #50 are made then the other initial block stops the simulation at time 200.  The #60 wants to execute at time 210, but the testbench is stopped at 200;

Run the testbench for more time.

Change this:

```
initial #200 $finish;
```

to this:

```
initial #2000 $finish;
```

Then you will see all the assignments in the wave window.

I put in some white space and print statements to help understand how the testbench executes.

```
// This is better
module t_Prob438();
  
reg [3:0]A,B;
reg enable_bar,select;
wire [3:0]Y;
  
Prob438 M0(A,B,enable_bar,select,Y);
  
initial 
  begin
    #2000;
    $finish;
  end
  
initial 
begin
  enable_bar=1;
  select=1;
  A=4'hA;
  B=4'h5;
  
  #10 select=0;
  #20 enable_bar=0;
  #30 A=4'h0;
  #40 A=4'hF;
  
  #50 enable_bar=1;
  $display("Here now at assign enable_bar equal 1 after #50, time = %0t",$time);
  
  // This statement and those following dont run in time 200
  #60 select=1;
  $display("Here now at assign select equal 1 after #60, time = %0t",$time);
  
  #70 enable_bar=0;
  #80 B=4'h0;
  #90 B=4'hA;
  #100 B=4'hF;
  #110 enable_bar=1;
  #120 select=0;
  #130 select=1;
  #140 enable_bar=1;
  $display("Got to the end at time = %0t",$time);
end

endmodule
```

This output is produced:

```
xcelium> run
Here now at assign enable_bar equal 1 after #50, time = 150
Here now at assign select equal 1 after #60, time = 210
Got to the end at time = 1050
Simulation complete via $finish(1) at time 2 US + 0
```